# 郵便番号と境界データ

Tags: google-maps, mapbox, 地理情報

日本の郵便番号ごとに境界データのGeoJsonを作りたいのですが、どのようにしたら作れますか?

郵便番号5桁だと下記のようなサイトがあったのですが、郵便番号7桁で作りたいです。
https://hanishina.github.io/maps/yubindata.html

Comment: 参照記事の作者に聞いてみてはどうでしょう？ X(Twitter)をやっているようですし。

Comment: ちなみに有料ならばデータやその商品は既に存在しているようですが。[郵便番号ポリゴンデータ2023](https://www.zenrin-ms.co.jp/gis_marketing/database/microcontents/zipcode_polygon/), [行政界ポリゴンデータ（PFM行政界）](https://www.pasco.co.jp/products/pfmg/), [住所・エリア・境界](https://www.gisdata-store.biz/genre/boundary/), [住所データ・住所ポリゴン・郵便番号データなどのGIS向けデータベース | MapFan DB](https://business.mapfan.com/service/db/address.php)